# Need a javascript code that will get the Y height of an object to use as a variable for scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

I need a javascript code that will retreive the Y position of a html object (in this case its "downarrow") so I can use it as a variable. Example:

```
        var topscrollvalue = // will be the Y of "downarrow"
        function scroll_to(){
        window.scrollTo({
            top: topscrollvalue, //value that will be scrolled
            left: 0,
            behavior:"smooth"
        }
        )
        }
```

basically i need the "topscrollvalue" variable to be the Y value of "downarrow" object in my html document.

Comment: this y position needed is from viewport or from beginning of document? In first case getboudinClientrect() will help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect. In second case offser.height will help you

Comment: I cant thank u enough.I got it working with getBoundingClientRect.